# Why can't I make a copy from the R window launched by vim?

Tags: linux, r, vim-plugin

I installed vim-r-plugin on my Linux system and it works great but just one issue makes me feel frustrated. The issue is that, after I launch the R window (It's a tmux terminal window actually) by `\rf`, I can't select and copy the content in the R window. Does somebody know the possible reasons and how to fixed it? my platform is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.1 (jessie)
Release:    8.1
Codename:   jessie
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean copy *from* the R console window and paste *to* vim? This is a tmux question more likely, but you can hold `Shift` while you are highlighting with the mouse, and then either middle-click to paste, or press `Shift+Insert`.

To send lines *from* vim *to* R, you will want to use the keyboard shortcuts provided by `vim-R`, such as `\ff` (which sends an entire function).